# Even though I filled in name, email, password, validation blocks signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am in the middle of Rails Tutorial. I thought I have almost finished chapter 7, but when I tried to sign up from the browser what I made, it does not make validation through. Could you please tell me why and what is going on?

I have tried to take a look sample codes here.
https://github.com/yasslab/sample_apps/tree/master/5_1_2/ch07,
but I could not find any solution for this error.

This appears on Avatar.

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  authenticity_token: uXdA0mb2W613nUOFg8K47fR9pvmwv69wxwByuzE+DF9SbMhQIPsuLEGsZyax9tmDJAyw4x9ektFwqcQ0dVqvgw==
  user: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    name: Rails Tutorial
    email: example@railstutorial.org
    password: pokopoko
    password_confirmation: pokopoko
  commit: Create my account
  controller: users
  action: create
permitted: false

# users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController      
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user_params])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end

# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum:  50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
end
```

error log is this.

```
Started POST "/signup" for 160.86.161.32 at 2019-02-05 02:14:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 160.86.161.32! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uXdA0mb2W613nUOFg8K47fR9pvmwv69wxwByuzE+DF9SbMhQIPsuLEGsZyax9tmDJAyw4x9ektFwqcQ0dVqvgw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Rails Tutorial", "email"=>"example@railstutorial.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 39.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

if I changed  `if @user.save` to  `if @user.save!`

another error message

Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password can't be blank

Comment: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up
This book is what I am learning from.
I wanted to make signup. I almost finished this chapter, then tried to sign up. I just could not sign up at all with any name, email, password. There is no error message on browser at all. Therefore it seems codes are working, but just cannot signup at all.

Comment: Maybe you have one more user with `example@railstutorial.org` email? Do you see any errors in rerendered form?

Comment: Please, add server log for signup action

Comment: Started POST "/signup" for 160.86.161.32 at 2019-02-05 02:14:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 160.86.161.32! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uXdA0mb2W613nUOFg8K47fR9pvmwv69wxwByuzE+DF9SbMhQIPsuLEGsZyax9tmDJAyw4x9ektFwqcQ0dVqvgw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Rails Tutorial", "email"=>"example@railstutorial.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}

Comment: (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 39.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

That is all. Anyway thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Please, edit the question and add logs to the question itself with proper formatting

Comment: OK, let's try to debug it. Change `if @user.save` in create action to `if @user.save!` - you'll the validation error in logs

Comment: another error.

Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password can't be blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the create action. You have `@user = User.new(params[:user_params])`. But there is no `user_params` key in the params. `user_params` is a method name, you have it in private part of the controller, and you define strong parameters in this method. Just change to

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

Comment: After I changed new action,
def new
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  end
another error
param is missing or the value is empty: user

Comment: @五十嵐伸雄, you need to change it only for `create` action. In `new` action it should be `User.new`, without any parameters

Comment: @五十嵐伸雄, please, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it helped. Happy to help you!